# How low does your health need to be to activate the "low health" part for a weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I put a low health part on my kunai for my spy. I was wondering how low my health needs to be in order to activate it. Also in general, what is the number for other classes too? Is it a number or a percentage of your health?

Comment: Good luck getting a low health kill with that one. In order for that to count, you'll have to be at 6 or less health.

Comment: 6 health or less, Thanks! It's a fun challenge for the kunai though. I got about 350 kills and 3 are low health kills! It's nice to know that the kunai saved me from an imminent death

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the TF2 Wiki, you would need less than 10% of your maximum health.

This is a bit hard to link, but if you go to the '[Strange Part](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_part)' page on the wiki, and mouse-over 'Strange Part: Low-health kills', under the 'List of strange parts' section, you would find the answer in the tool-tip that appears.